# Hyperbolic paraboloid: how to find the distance from a point on the surface to the $z$-axis?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, 3d, quadrics

The given hyperbolic paraboloid is $z=xy$. How do I find the distance $r$ from a point on the surface to the $z$-axis?

I used a function grapher to visualize the 3-D surface. But I am unable to understand how to calculate the required distance $r$. I am very poor at interpreting 3-D surfaces. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given any point $(x, y, z)$, the distance to the $z$ axis is $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.  This has nothing to do with the point lying on a paraboloid.

Comment: But doesn't this depend on the nature of the curve? Given any point (x,y,z), the will the distance to x axis be √(y^2 +z^2) ?

Comment: Distance to *blah* is the length of the shortest possible straight line that ends at *blah*.  It does not depend on what curve or surface or whatnot your point lies on.  And yes, that is the distance to the $x$ axis.

Comment: Thanks! This is so simple. Sorry, for the silly question. The whole 3D thing had confused me.